# On proving the following inequality: $ \int_X \text{min}(f,g) \ d\mu \geq \frac{1}{2} (\int_X \sqrt{fg} \ d\mu)^2. $

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, lebesgue-integral

Let $f,g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote bounded, non-negative, measurable functions and $\mu$ a measure on $X$.

Then I would like to prove that

> $$
> \int_X \text{min}(f,g) \ d\mu \geq \frac{1}{2} (\int_X \sqrt{fg} \ d\mu)^2.
> $$

What I have tried so far is writing $\text{min}(f,g)= \frac{f+g}{2} - \frac{\vert f - g \vert}{2}$. Then it is a well-known result that $\frac{f+g}{2} \geq \sqrt{fg}$ which seems promising (but might not be what we need though). I am not sure what to do about the second term. Also there needs to appear a square outside the integral which could be achieved with for instance Jensen's Inequality due to the convexity of $x \mapsto x^2$. Then it would suffice to prove that

$$
\int_X f+g - \vert f - g \vert \ d\mu \geq \int_X fg \ d\mu.
$$
Here I am stuck. Can anyone help me? Am I on the right track?

*As a final remark, it would be okay if we need to assume that $f,g$ integrate to 1 and $\mu(X)=1$ (as they will be densities for probability measures in the context I will be using this inequality). However I am not sure whether or not this is a necessary assumption and hence I have stated the problem without it initially.*

Comment: It certainly isn't true in general.  Think of the transformation $f \to cf$, $g \to g/c$ for positive constant $c$, which leaves the right side invariant but makes the left go to $0$ as $c \to 0$.  If you want densities for probability measures, you **don't** want $f$ and $g$ to be bounded by $1$, rather $\int_X f\; d\mu = \int_X g\; d\mu = 1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will update the remark!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution where we assume $\mu$ is a probability measure and $f,g$ integrate to 1 i.e.
$$
\int_X f \ d\mu = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \int_X g \ d\mu = 1.
$$

Using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality
\begin{align*}
(\int_{X} \sqrt{fg} \ d\mu)^2 &= (\int_{X} \sqrt{\text{min}\{f,g\}\text{max}\{f,g\}} \ d\mu)^2 \leq \int_{X} \text{min}\{f,g\} \ d\mu \cdot \int_{X} \text{max}\{f,g\} \ d\mu \\
&\leq \int_{X} \text{min}\{f,g\} \ d\mu \cdot \int_{X} \text{max}\{f,g\} + \text{min}\{f,g\} \ d\mu \\
&= \int_{X} \text{min}\{f,g\} \ d\mu \cdot \int_{X} 2(\frac{f+g}{2}) \ d\mu \\
&= 2\int_{X} \text{min}\{f,g\} \ d\mu
\end{align*}
as desired.